# How to center the whole image comparison slider

Tags: javascript, css, image, center

When I manage to move the image comparison slider, the actual 'slider' left behind. The slider JS code is from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp

and can be easily inspect there but I will paste the code in here too.
I have tried to move the slider with Css grid but the as mentioned before the slider icon won't move with the images.

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /* Find all elements with an "overlay" class: */
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /* Once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function: */
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }
  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
    /* Get the width and height of the img element */
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /* Set the width of the img element to 50%: */
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /* Create slider: */
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /* Insert slider */
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /* Position the slider in the middle: */
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /* Execute a function when the mouse button is pressed: */
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /* And another function when the mouse button is released: */
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /* Or touched (for touch screens: */
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
     /* And released (for touch screens: */
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);
    function slideReady(e) {
      /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image: */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* The slider is now clicked and ready to move: */
      clicked = 1;
      /* Execute a function when the slider is moved: */
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }
    function slideFinish() {
      /* The slider is no longer clicked: */
      clicked = 0;
    }
    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /* If the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function: */
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /* Get the cursor's x position: */
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /* Prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image: */
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /* Execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor: */
      slide(pos);
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /* Get the x positions of the image: */
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /* Calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image: */
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /* Consider any page scrolling: */
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }
    function slide(x) {
      /* Resize the image: */
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /* Position the slider: */
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

initComparisons();
```

```css
  .img-comp-container {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 100vw
   }

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

  .img-comp-img img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  .img-comp-slider {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: ew-resize;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px 0 9px 14px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-comp-container">
    <div class="img-comp-img">
      <img src="img/ysl_before.jpg" width="650" height="450">
    </div>
    <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
      <img src="img/ysl_after.jpg" width="650" height="450">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the supplied code seems to be working here perhaps you used the wrong name for one of the image src?

Comment: The supplied code does not center the slider on the website, hope this clarifies what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this fixes what you are looking for:

Wrap the existing container in another div (img-comp-outer-container), remove margin from img-comp-container and set height/width of img-comp-container to auto.

You can then style the outer container to align the component how you like

```html
<div class="img-comp-outer-container"> <!--new div -->
  <div class="img-comp-container">
    <div class="img-comp-img">
      <img src="img_snow.jpg" width="650" height="450">
    </div>
    <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
      <img src="img_forest.jpg" width="650" height="450">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!--new div end -->
```

```css
.img-comp-outer-container {
  /* add your styles to move around component */
}

.img-comp-container {
  /* margin: auto; */
  position: relative;
  height: auto; /* was 100vh */
  width: auto; /* was 100vw */
}
```

Comment: Hi Nolan, sorry to be so clueless but I have edit the code as you have recommended and tried to set the .img-comp-outer-container  margin: 0 auto; But it still wont center the whole slider. What would you recommend to center?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to bring the two images, that I'm comparing using image compare slider to the center of the page. The code available on W3Schools to compare images using slider but there was not suggestion about centering it. So what I did was I placed div id box and added all other classes into it and styled the box as white with height and width and added float-right to the img-comp-container. You can change the width and height of box accordingly to center the slider.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-comp-container {
  float: right; /*new change*/
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; /*should be the same height as the images*/
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display:block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/*new change*/
#box{ 
background: white;
width: 150px;
height: 200px;
}
</style>
<script>
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /*once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }
  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0, w, h;
    /*get the width and height of the img element*/
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /*create slider:*/
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /*insert slider*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /*position the slider in the middle:*/
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
    /*and released (for touch screens:*/
    window.addEventListener("touchend", slideFinish);
    function slideReady(e) {
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
      clicked = 1;
      /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }
    function slideFinish() {
      /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
      clicked = 0;
    }
    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /*get the cursor's x position:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
      slide(pos);
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }
    function slide(x) {
      /*resize the image:*/
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /*position the slider:*/
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Compare Two Images</h1>

<p>Click and slide the blue slider to compare two images:</p>
<div id="box">/*new change*/
<div class="img-comp-container">
  <div class="img-comp-img">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
/*Execute a function that will execute an image compare function for each element with the img-comp-overlay class:*/
initComparisons();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```